# Same form but have input do something else

Tags: php, mysql

just created a 'changedetails.php' page where users are able to change their details such as 'password' and 'email'. They all work successful but I am trying to allow a user to change their email without having to change their password as well.

So basically, if a user only wanted to change their email it will update in the DB without having to change their passwords.

Code:

```
<title>Honda |</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

<?php
session_start();

$username = $_SESSION['sess_user'];

echo '<div class="search1"><h2>'.$username.'</h2></div>';

if (isset($_SESSION['sess_user'])) {
    //user is logged in
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        //start changing password
        //check fields

        $oldpassword = md5($_POST['oldpassword']);
        $newpassword = md5($_POST['newpassword']);
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $repeatnewpassword = md5($_POST['repeatnewpassword']);


        //check password against db
        include('../includes/config.php');

        $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT password 
                                 FROM login 
                                 WHERE username='$username'") 
                    or die ("change password failed");
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryget);
        $oldpassworddb = $row['password'];

        //check passwords
        if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb) {
            //check two new passwords
            if ($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword) {
                //successs
                //change password in db

                $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login 
                                            SET password='$newpassword' 
                                            WHERE username='$username'");
                $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login 
                                            SET email='$email' 
                                            WHERE username='$username'");
                die("<div class='successmate'>
                     Your password has been changed. <a href='index2.php'>
                     <br><br> Return</a></div>");
            } else {
                die("<div class='results'>New password doesn't match!</div>");
            }
        } else {
            die("<div class='results'>Old password doesn't match!</div>");
        }
    } else {
        echo "<form class='search1' action='changepassword.php' method='POST'>";
        echo "<label>Old Password:</label> <input type='password' id='password' name='oldpassword'>";
        echo "<p><label>New Password:</label> ";
        echo "<input type='password' id='password' name='newpassword'>";
        echo "<p><label>Repeat New Password:</label> ";
        echo "<input type='password'  name='repeatnewpassword'><p>";
        echo "<label>Email:</label> <input type='email'  name='email'>";
        echo "<p><input type='submit' name='submit' class='submit' value='submit'>";
        echo "<br><br><br><h2><p><a href='index2.php'>Back</a></p></h2></form>";
     }
 } else { 
     die ("You must be logged in to change your password");
 }

 ?>

<img src="../images/main.jpg">
```

Thanks!

UPDATE 2:

```
if ($newpassword != "")  {
  //check passwords
  if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb)
  {
  //check two new passwords
  if ($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword)
  {
  //successs
  //change password in db

  $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET password='$newpassword' WHERE username='$username'");
  }
  else 
die("<div class='results'>New password doesn't match!</div>");


}else 
die("<div class='results'>Old password doesn't match!</div>");

}

}


if ($email != "")  {
$querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET email='$email' WHERE   username='$username'");
die("<div class='successmate'>Your password has been changed. <a href='index2.php'><br><br> Return</a></div>");
}

}
else
{

echo"
<form class='search1' action='changepassword.php' method='POST'>
<label>Current Password:</label> <input type='password' id='password' name='oldpassword'><p>
<label>New Password:</label> <input type='password' id='password' name='newpassword'><p>
<label>Repeat New Password:</label> <input type='password'  name='repeatnewpassword'><p>
<label>Email:</label> <input type='email'  name='email'><p>
<input type='submit' name='submit' class='submit' value='submit'><br><br><br>
<h2><p><a href='index2.php'>Back</a></p></h2>
</form>
";
 }

 {else 
die ("You must be logged in to change your password");


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are running the 2 queries right after each other, you need to add a check to see if password is blank, then skip password query, if email is blank then skip email query

**EDIT:**

```
if ($newpassword != "")  {
  //check passwords
  if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb)
  {
  //check two new passwords
  if ($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword)
  {
  //successs
  //change password in db

  $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET password='$newpassword' WHERE username='$username'");
  else 
die("<div class='results'>New password doesn't match!</div>");

}else 
die("<div class='results'>Old password doesn't match!</div>");

}

}


if ($email != "")  {
$querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET email='$email' WHERE   username='$username'");
die("<div class='successmate'>Your password has been changed. <a href='index2.php'><br><br> Return</a></div>");
}
```

**FULL CODE SET(Requested by OP)**

```
<title>Honda |</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

<?php
session_start();

$username = $_SESSION['sess_user'];

echo '<div class="search1"><h2>'.$username.'</h2></div>';

if (isset($_SESSION['sess_user'])) {
    //user is logged in
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        //start changing password
        //check fields

        $oldpassword = md5($_POST['oldpassword']);
        $newpassword = md5($_POST['newpassword']);
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $repeatnewpassword = md5($_POST['repeatnewpassword']);


        //check password against db
        include('../includes/config.php');

        $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM login WHERE username='$username'") 
                or die ("change password failed");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryget);
    $oldpassworddb = $row['password'];

    if ($newpassword != "")   {
        //check passwords
        if ($oldpassword==$oldpassworddb) {
            //check two new passwords
            if ($newpassword==$repeatnewpassword) {
               //successs
               //change password in db

               $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET password='$newpassword' WHERE username='$username'");


     die("<div class='successmate'>
                 Your password has been changed. <a href='index2.php'>
                 <br><br> Return</a></div>");
        } else {
            die("<div class='results'>New password doesn't match!</div>");
        }
    } else {
        die("<div class='results'>Old password doesn't match!</div>");
    }

    }

            if ($email != "")    {
                $querychange = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET email='$email' WHERE username='$username'");

die("<div class='successmate'>
                 Your email been changed. <a href='index2.php'>
                 <br><br> Return</a></div>");

            }
                } else {
    echo "<form class='search1' action='changepassword.php' method='POST'>";
    echo "<label>Old Password:</label> <input type='password' id='password' name='oldpassword'>";
    echo "<p><label>New Password:</label> ";
    echo "<input type='password' id='password' name='newpassword'>";
    echo "<p><label>Repeat New Password:</label> ";
    echo "<input type='password'  name='repeatnewpassword'><p>";
    echo "<label>Email:</label> <input type='email'  name='email'>";
    echo "<p><input type='submit' name='submit' class='submit' value='submit'>";
    echo "<br><br><br><h2><p><a href='index2.php'>Back</a></p></h2></form>";
 }
 } else { 
     die ("You must be logged in to change your password");
 }

 ?>

<img src="../images/main.jpg">
```

Comment: Hi there, if it's not an issue are you able to edit my code to what you think is right? I am having some issues.

Comment: I made a change, try that

Comment: Sorry, I had made a mistake in my code, I have now fixed it

Comment: Same thing :( If I try to change the email only. Still says' Old password doesn't match'

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the earlier checks, I have now added those check within the check to make sure newpassword is not blank, email is still on its own, you may need to add/remove some brackets as I may have miscounted those

Comment: Thanks for helping me out just have some issues, I am unsure of where to update it as you have pasted partial code in. If it's possible can you update my code above and add yours? Also I've edited my post above and I am unsure of where "{" are missing as it's hard to tell.

Comment: Hi, I have posted the full code set, try that, let me know if there are any further errors, and I will make ammendments

Comment: Still getting the 'Old password doesn't match', :(.

Comment: Can you confirm that when you try to just change the email that the password textbox is 100% empty, no spaces, tabs, etc

Comment: Yeah I tried that and I still get 'Old password doesn't match'. Also when I change password etc and email the email doesn't update in the db :s?

Comment: I'll rebuild this project on my local server after work and then i will be able to update you with 100% tested and working code

Comment: Thank you so much, I was struggling with this for 2 days. I'll be checking regularly!